# how to send a vector of string in mpi?

Tags: c++, vector, mpi

I want to send a vector of string in MPI,but I don't know how should I use the MPI_Send and MPI_receiev. for example if I want to send a vector of `long` I will use this code:

```
vector<double> local_data(n);

 MPI_Send(&local_data[0], n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

but if I want to send a vector of string like this

```
vector<std::string> local_data(n);
```

I don't know what should I use as the `size of buffer` and the type of `variable` in MPI_send,
or MPI_recive. is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send strings in MPI, you have to convert them to C style char arrays first. There isn't an `MPI_STRING` type (unless you're using some non-standard extensions). When you convert to the c_str, you should be able to get the size of the string and use that as the size input for the `MPI_SEND` or `MPI_RECV`.

Comment: thank  you so much,I Understood that I can not send an string directly in MPI, and I found how to send a single string in MPI, but now I want to send a vector of string,what is the best solution for it?

Comment: The result is the same. Either you send with multiple calls to `MPI_SEND` or you can concatenate all of the strings together and send them as one big string. I'd propose that the first is a lot easier. Just queue up a bunch of calls to `MPI_ISEND` and do them all at once.

Comment: thank you again,and I have another question too,which one is better:sending a huge buffer one time or sending too smaller messages 3 times more times but in different times of executing the program not in one time?

Comment: You should really split your extra questions out into another question on SO. I'll be happy to answer it there, but it becomes confusing for future visitors if they chain up like this.