# MPI - Send a std::vector<string> to another group of process

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to send a vector to a group of process that are created using ***MPI_Comm_spawn***.I have try everything on the internet but i con't solve it yet. *Until now i manage to make this separate groups to communicate and the parend sends an int to the workers. I need to make it work with a std::vector*

For parent

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    int my_rank; /* rank of process */
    int p; /* number of processes */

    /* start up MPI */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    /* find out process rank */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    /* find out number of processes */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    MPI_Group grp_world;
    MPI_Group grp_new;
    MPI_Comm newComm;

    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &grp_world); // get the group of processes for MPI_COMM_WORLD communicator

    MPI_Group_incl(grp_world, 1, &my_rank, &grp_new); // create a new group with only one member (my_rank process)

    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, grp_new, &newComm); // create a new communicator for the new group

    int my_rank_grp; /* rank of process in grp_new */
    int p_grp; /* number of processes in grp_new */
    /* find out process rank in the new group */
    MPI_Comm_rank(newComm, &my_rank_grp);
    /* find out number of processes of the new group */
    MPI_Comm_size(newComm, &p_grp);

    printf("Process rank/size in WORLD/OWN GROUP: [%d/%d]/[%d/%d]\n",
            my_rank, p, my_rank_grp, p_grp);

    MPI_Comm workercomm; // intercommunicator
    int b = my_rank; // some data to be sent

    //[!!!] due to some MPI implementation problems, parallel calls the MPI_Comm_spawn trigger an error, so for the moment we just serialize these calls.
    for (i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        if (i == my_rank) {
            MPI_Comm_spawn("/home/workspace_test/worker/Debug/worker",
                    MPI_ARGV_NULL, 3, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, newComm, &workercomm,
                    MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE );
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }

    /* collective communication sample */
    MPI_Bcast(&b, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ROOT, workercomm);
    MPI_Comm_free(&workercomm);

    /* shut down MPI */
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

And after this i have a simple worker:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int my_rank; /* rank of process */
    int p; /* number of processes */
    int p_remote; /* number of processes in parent group */

    /* start up MPI */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    /* find out process rank */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    /* find out number of processes */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    MPI_Comm parentcomm; // intercommunicator
    int b; // some data to be received

    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parentcomm);

    /* find out number of processes in parent group */
    MPI_Comm_remote_size(parentcomm, &p_remote);


    MPI_Bcast(&b, 1, MPI_INT, 0, parentcomm);

    printf("[%d] Worker process: %d. Parent group size: %d!\n", b, my_rank, p_remote);

    MPI_Comm_free(&parentcomm);

    /* shut down MPI */
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

All is good with this simple int Bcast but if i try to send a vector things dosen't work how i expect.

What i am trying to do?

I have a vector with paths (files from disk) and the number of paths will be divided to the number of process. Each process will receive a block of files and this process for each file will launch a worker proces that will make some verification on file.

What i try until now:

- I have read and i sow that MPI dosen't have something like MPI_STRING but also if I cast string to char* things aren't better.
- I have tried the idea from this prezentation [std::vector/std::String in MPI](https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/images/f/fa/MPI_Datatypes_with_Opaque_Types_seminar_2014.pdf) but still i have the some problem.

Maybe someone with some experience with mpi can give me some hints about how can i send the entire vector.

Thank you.

//edit

I have try to send data like this:
On partent:

```
std::vector<std::string> m_image_data2;
m_image_data2.push_back("test");
m_image_data2.push_back("test");
m_image_data2.push_back("test");
m_image_data2.push_back("test");
m_image_data2.push_back("test");
char* data = const_cast<char*>(m_image_data2[0].c_str());
MPI_Bcast(data, 5, MPI_CHAR, MPI_ROOT, workercomm);
MPI_Comm_free(&workercomm);
```

And on the worker side:

```
/* find out number of processes in parent group */
MPI_Comm_remote_size(parentcomm, &p_remote);
std::vector<std::string> m_image_data2;
MPI_Bcast(&m_image_data2, 5, MPI_CHAR, 0, parentcomm);
```

So my problem right now appear when i try to send a vector of string between a spawned task.

Comment: Your question is too noisy. Create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - minimal, complete, verifiable example. Is the spawning part really needed? (my guess -  it's not. But you'll get a step closer to the solution by removing it and finding out). What use of strings did you try, and what didn't work? Show the code and show the errors. Right now, there's too much information missing. Make the question much more focused on the exact issue if you'd like to get useful answers.

Comment: As a matter of style, you can use `MPI_COMM_SELF` instead of (suboptimally creating)  `newComm`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387320/how-to-send-a-vector-of-string-in-mpi

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet is not a duplicate. I don't know the id of the proces created by MPI_Comm_spawn., so i con't use MPI_Send.

Comment: @eran I made some changes on the previous post. I added how i am trying to send the vector right now.

Comment: As pointed earlier, you should really build one [MCVE] per single issue. So what is your issue ? send a vector of string between two process (and in this case, your issue is really with `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`) ? send an integer to a spawned task ? and in this case, your issue is with intercommunicators ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet my problem is to send a vector of strings between a spawned task.

Comment: you obviously have two distinct problems 1) you do not know how to send a vector of strings to itself (read MPI_Sendrecv(...,MPI_COMM_SELF,...)) 2) you do not know how to use intercommunicators. The right way to ask on SO is via two distinct questions, and each of them with its own

Comment: I con't use MPI_Sendrecv or send because i don't know the rank of the new created proces.

Comment: That's why I suggest you use `MPI_COMM_SELF`, you only need one MPI task, and zero spawn.

Comment: I never heard abou tMPI_COMM_SELF. I will search to see how this will solve my problem. Thanks @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: just to be clear, `MPI_COMM_SELF` will **not** solve (one of) your problem. But it will help **you** understand it and write a [MCVE] as @eran and I already suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the following code to see your mistakes.

**master.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

// Converts vector<string> to vector<char>.
std::vector<char> string_to_char(const std::vector<std::string>& strings) {
    std::vector<char> cstrings;
    cstrings.reserve(strings.size());
    for(std::string s: strings)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s.c_str()); ++i)
        {
            cstrings.push_back(s.c_str()[i]);
        }
    }

    return cstrings;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
    std::vector<char> cstrings = string_to_char(m_image_data2);
    MPI_Bcast(cstrings.data(), cstrings.size(), MPI_CHAR, MPI_ROOT, workercomm);
    ...
}
```

**worker.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...    
    std::vector<char> cstrings(20);
    MPI_Bcast(cstrings.data(), 20, MPI_CHAR, 0, parentcomm);

    // cstrings: testtesttesttesttest
    // print first four chars.
    printf("Worker process: %c%c%c%c\n", cstrings[0], cstrings[1], cstrings[2], cstrings[3]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a big change. I was thinking is enough to convert the current string to a const char* but from your example i understand this is not. I manage to send the vector to the worker process by passing the entire vector as a comand line when he is created. Yor example is much clean and better. thanks